# NullPointerException GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap 4.0.3 & 4.0.4

Tags: android, performance

i saw crash reports of my application on play store and , i have no idea about this issue. i want to understand that If i use  "hardwareAccelerated false" , is it useful method?. or what is the reason of this problem? how can i solve this problem. devices that have 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 are came across  with this crash

crash log : https://gist.github.com/semihozkoroglu/30be3fda7257d002e2fe

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10968)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:1067)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10986)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can fix this problem by using one of the `drawBitmap` methods that accepts as an argument the rectangle of the source image you want to render. It's a bug in a few specific versions of Android, where the default behaviour of drawing the whole image to the canvas doesn't work.

Assuming you want the whole bitmap drawn, your code might look like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), bitmapPosition, paint);
```

Comment: hi @dave, thanks for reply but, i can't render any image,  i am only using ImageView on SlidingMenu left menu. And this crash  happened when the base class calles com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw, i think that this problem is about OpenGL ES 2.0. Maybe you can check it out

Comment: You may have to fallback to disabling hardware acceleration for specific versions of Android, and if you support older versions you'll need to use reflection to do it. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use animation, maybe you can try post “remove the view” to UI thread?
I met the same stack as you. But I think this is the root cause.

[How to remove a View when animation ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025163/how-to-remove-a-view-when-animation-ends/4295570#4295570)