# Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference

Tags: android, crash

We are getting the below exception on our production app but there is nothing mentioned about our app classes. Its difficult to figure out where the issue is coming and also we are not able to replicate in our devices.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15158)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:282)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:288)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:323)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2461)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2094)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I had seen some links which are similar to my issue but that doesn't help me too. Below are the links i saw :

[Android ViewGroup crash: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242776/android-viewgroup-crash-attempt-to-read-from-field-int-android-view-view-mview)

[getting NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' - Android animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821727/getting-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-read-from-field-int-android-view-view/41822106)

If anyone had faced same issue and have some solution please do let me know.

Also do let me know if you need more information.

Thank You for your time. :)

Comment: Check this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242776/android-viewgroup-crash-attempt-to-read-from-field-int-android-view-view-mview)